# how to make the search box auto position and auto resize irrespective of the screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a responsive website for my project but I'm stuck with the absolute position of my search bar on the main page, which is very important to me.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="span4">

<form class="well form-search" 

style="position:fixed; display:block; 

left: 50%; top: 35.5%; 

margin-top: -12.5px;  

margin-left: -150px;" 

action="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/search-results/">

<input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" value="I am Searching For" 

style="width: 300px; height: 25px; ">

<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" > GO </button>

</form>

</div>

</div>
```

I have search a lot, seen examples but to make it responsive, then changed the position from pixel to percentage, but still the problem exists.

On Desktop it looks fine but the problem is when I see it on mobile phones or ipads the search box placement is not changed. I just want to fix the box position irrespective to screen resolution on different screen sizes.

---

I have changed the code and it works a little more fine, except the button The Go button here is breaking the line and going down. I want it in to same line. Please check the code:

```
<form class="well form-search" 
style="position:absolute; display:block; 

left: 47.7%; top: 29.5%; 
margin-top: -12.5px;  
margin-left: -22.5%;


width: -webkit-calc(47.7% - 10px);
width: -moz-calc(47.7% - 10px);
width: calc(47.7% - 10px);"


action="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/search-results-jobs/">
<input type="text" class="input-medium search-query"              
value=" I am Looking For" 

style="width: 100%; height: 25px;

width: -webkit-calc(100% - 10px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 10px);
width: calc(100% - 10px);">

<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" > GO </button></center>
</form>
```

Comment: GO?

No, I don't think so. Plus there is no code.

Answer (score 0):

Read this blog
http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/
about fixed positioning on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for the Link. But it didn't help in resizing the search bar across different screen sizes. I want to make the same website "search bar" to automatic resize at the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/4bPuT/1/

If I understand correctly, what you could do in an absolute positioned input is to set both left and right css attributes to 0 so that it get the maximum width of the current container.

```
<div class="container">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="I resize">

    <!-- other content -->

</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}

.container #search{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much... I tried with the above code it works but again, I want to make it fixed at a certain position different screen sizes. First the search bar position was static i.e. left: 500px; top: 246px; then I change it to pixels i.e. left: 50%; top: 35.5%; which works but not properly fine on diff screen sizes. Moreover I have to maintain the width and height of the search bar according to the screen size but on the desktop version it has to be "width: 300px; height: 25px; Thanks

Comment: Then you might be interested in media queries. Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/